# Realtime синхронизация двух баз данных MySQL

Tags: mysql, репликация

Подскажите, какие существуют решения для синхронизации в реальном времени двух баз данных MySQL.

Comment: Это называется репликация, по английски replication.

Comment: MySQL-репликация не гарантирует синхронизацию в реальном времени, поэтому она ему не подходит. При малом объёме записей MySQL-репликация может работать **почти как** real-time синхронизация, но всё-таки она не будет являться таковой.

Comment: @PavelIvanov нужно уточнение от автора, вдруг «почти» ему тоже подходит)

Comment: @PavelIvanov так реалтайма не существует в распределенных системах

Comment: @etki чисто теоретически можно заблокировать текущую транзакцию до тех пор, пока все базы не синхронизируются друг с другом, для клиентских приложений это будет выглядеть как реалтайм. Правда, я не слышал, чтобы в mysql так было можно

Comment: @etki, согласен. Абсолютного реалтайма не существует. Но в IT под реалтаймом мы понимаем не абсолют, а реакцию на внешние событие **в рамках заданных временных ограничений**. Так вот MySQL не гарантирует выдержку этих ограничений при росте апдейтов данных. 10 инсертов она будет синхронизировать за 0.001 сек., а 2000 инсертов за 5 сек. Хотя это вполне может устраивать автора.

Comment: @andreymal это тоже не реалтайм (строку с мастера можно прочитать до ее полной записи), и, к тому же, ломается при первой ошибке

Comment: В общем по базам идет активная запись. В этой ситуации непредсказуемость варианта репликации мастер-мастер пугает, отсюда и вопрос. На блокировку транзакций до конца синхронизации согласен.

Comment: Варианты [proxysql]+[репликация master-slave] когда запись идет только в master, не подходит т.к. каждая из баз должна быть чтение-запись.